# ASP.NET 5 Web api template, unresolved reference System.Web

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

My ASP.NET 5 Web api project fails to build when adding a reference to `System.Web`

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Project
2. Select the ASP.NET 5 Web API template
3. Right click references and add System.Web
4. Add `using System.Web;` to some class

Exact error code:

`CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  Stackoverflow.DNX Core 5.0  D:\Git\Stackoverflow\src\Stackoverflow\Startup.cs   10  Active`

What I tried to do next is add:

```
"dnxcore50": {
  "frameworkAssemblies": {
    "System.Web": "4.0.0.0"
  }
}
```

To the project.json file under the `"Frameworks"` tag after restoring packages this resulted in an unresolved dependency issue.

The solution DNX SDK version is: `1.0.0-rc1-update1` (which is the only option listed in my Visual Studio)

After a quick google search for any workaround left me empty handed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.Net 5 is no longer based on System.Web and there is not .net core compatible implementation of it. But there are many nuget packages so probably you will find the expected feature.

For example:
Instead of System.Web.Mvc, you need to add Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc nuget package to your project and you will be able to use the controller base class.

Comment: Do you happen to know any nuget package that would fill the need for Authentication?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication/

Comment: Ty sir I'll give it a try :)